# uwp create xaml or new page dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am new to uwp, I don't want to create multiple static xaml file, how to create new page, add dynamic controls to that page and navigate

```
namespace UItest
{
   // <summary>
   // An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a 
   // </summary>
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
     public MainPage()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
     private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     { 
       Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2));
     }
   }

   public sealed partial class page2 : Page
   {
     public page2()
     {
        Button bt = new Button();
         bt.Content = "page2";
      } 
   }
}
```

In above code I am trying to create new class(page2), in button click event it should navigate to page

Comment: So what is the issue? Does the button not navigate correctly, or the new page is not showing your button?

Comment: No it is throwing AccessViolationException. I am not creating proper page itself, I don't know how to create page dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is possible, maybe is, as most of XAML things can be also done in the code behind. Nevertheless, maybe try something different - create one basic template of a page - let's call it *MultiPage*, and redesign it on *OnNavigatedTo* basing on suitable passed argument. A short sample - *MultiPage's* code behind:

```
public enum PageType { First, Second }

public sealed partial class MultiPage : Page
{
    public MultiPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        switch ((PageType)e.Parameter)
        {
            case PageType.First:
                this.Content = new Button { Content = "First page" };
                break;
            case PageType.Second:
                this.Content = new Button { Content = "Second page" };
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and way of navigation to that page:

```
private void FirstClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiPage), PageType.First);
}

private void SecondClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MultiPage), PageType.Second);
}
```

Comment: It worked for single page, assume Mainpage -> Multipage(First) -> Multipage(Second), if I click back button it is navigating to mainpage it should navigate back to Multipage(First)

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARS Then this method won't work for you - it's operating on the same instance of a page, though with different contents.